# Preload responsive images in a <picture> tag

Tags: preload, responsive-images

I need to preload responsive images that are set in a `<picture>` tag:

```
<picture>
<source sizes="(max-width: 320px) 320px, (max-width: 480px) 480px, (max-width: 768px) 768px, (max-width: 1024px) 1024px, (max-width: 1200px) 1200px, 1500px" srcset="home-image1-bis2-1200x640.webp 1200w, home-image1-bis2-1024x546.webp 1024w, home-image1-bis2-768x410.webp 768w, home-image1-bis2-480x256.webp 480w, home-image1-bis2-320x171.webp 320w, home-image1-bis2.webp 1500w" type="image/webp">
</picture>
```

I've found this link: https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/
and I tried to apply it like this:

```
<link rel="preload" href=home-image1-bis2-320x171.webp" as="image" type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 320px)">
<link rel="preload" href="home-image1-bis2-480x256.webp" as="image" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 320.1px) and (max-width: 480px)">
<link rel="preload" href="home-image1-bis2-768x410.webp" as="image" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 480.1px) and (max-width: 768px)">
<link rel="preload" href="home-image1-bis2-1024x546.webp" as="image" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 768.1px) and (max-width: 1024px)">
<link rel="preload" href="home-image1-bis2-1024x546.webp" as="image" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 1024.1px) and (max-width: 1200px)"><link rel="preload" href="home-image1-bis2.webp" as="image" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 1200.1px)">
```

It doesn't seem to be working, also the console now logs this notice:

> The resource *home-image1-bis2-480x256.webp* was preloaded using link
> preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load
> event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is
> preloaded intentionally.

And this has no impact on the LCP of the lighthouse score.
How do I load the images properly?

Comment: anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `imagesrcset` and `imagesizes` attributes for this use case:

```
<link 
    rel="preload"
    as="image"
    type="image/webp"
    imagesrcset="home-image1-bis2-1200x640.webp 1200w, home-image1-bis2-1024x546.webp 1024w, home-image1-bis2-768x410.webp 768w, home-image1-bis2-480x256.webp 480w, home-image1-bis2-320x171.webp 320w, home-image1-bis2.webp 1500w"
    imagesizes="(max-width: 320px) 320px, (max-width: 480px) 480px, (max-width: 768px) 768px, (max-width: 1024px) 1024px, (max-width: 1200px) 1200px, 1500px"
>
```

See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-imagesrcset
and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-imagesizes

Comment: These are currently not supported in Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#browser_compatibility

Comment: Hint: They are supported now since the release of iOS 17.2.